# How to create a folder in HOME Folder with ModelBuilder in ArcGis 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am just getting started with ModelBuilder and I would like to create a folder in the same folder where the respective mxd is located.
The tool have to be usable in different projects, so setting Current Workspace to a specific folder doesn't do the trick.

Is there any chance to get access to a path of the Home folder which would be the same in any given project?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you'll be able to create a folder directly from Model Builder, but you can write a script that does it and call it from within Model Builder, as discussed in [Integrating Scripts within a Model](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Integrating_scripts_within_a_model/002w0000006n000000/).

Here would be an example script that creates a folder in the directory of the current mxd:

```py
from os.path import split, join, splitext, exists
from os import makedirs

#Get path to currently opened mxd.
filepath = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current').filePath

#Split directory from path name.
maindir, mxd = split(filepath)

#Path to new folder, which is named after mxd (minus the .mxd).
folder = join(maindir, splitext(mxd)[0])

#Create folder if it doesn't exist
if not exists(folder):
    makedirs(folder)
```

Comment: The code above can be placed in a Calculate value model only tool and this can be part of your model. It's output could be a Boolean indicating a successful creation of a folder which is then a precondition to the rest of the model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried it already, but it seems that there is a problem with the different Python versions I have installed. After I figured that out I will tell you if it worked.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using model builder.
Use the [Create Folder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Folder/0017000000pz000000/) and [Parse Path](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Parse_Path/004000000008000000/) tools. Set the **Parse Type** in the **Parse Path** tool to **PATH**. Connect **Value** as a precondition to Create Folder. In the Folder location variable, type in **%Value%**

[image]

Comment: The problem with your solution is, that the user has to set the path/mxd by himself and so has to browse through the file system. That's something I am trying to avoid.