# Using Modelbuilder or Python to write output a folder name using database or table file?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, table

Has anyone worked on Modelbuilder or python to write to automate creating a folder using the database or table file to write output a folder name and or/create the subfolders? I recalled I had an aml that allowed me to modify codes to allow to output new folders within the folder.

For example, you have a database that has the list of the name of the counties on the dbf file or table and then insert it to the Modelbuilder. Example name of county : Dona Ana and then use that name to create a folder Dona Ana  ( to hold imagery for NAIP on the server when I get all of the New Mexico counties in a hard drive to me)

[How to create a folder in HOME Folder with ModelBuilder in ArcGis 10?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68390/how-to-create-a-folder-in-home-folder-with-modelbuilder-in-arcgis-10)

I'm adding this screenshot to show what I am doing wrong... ( This is the pre-screenshot)
that was done yesterday December 9th.
[image]

Now that that i have figured it out and here is the screenshot December 10th.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this already answered by the earlier Q&A that you have linked to?  If not, would you be able to edit your question to clarify whether you are preferring a ModelBuilder only solution, please?  This is a case where I think ModelBuilder probably can meet your requirements but I think we need you to edit your question to provide more details around what precisely is in your "database or table file" and what your model looks like so far.

Comment: I would say it's adequately explained there. Is there a snippet of the table we can see and matching folder tree to comprehend what you're trying to do.

Comment: Providing more details of your precise requirements should enable us to see whether there is anything not covered in the earlier Q&A, and if so, to then quickly re-open your question to address them.

Comment: @PolyGeo  Ok I will need to wait til tomorrow and will put up a screenshot here.

Comment: In the example from your question, what folder will the Dona Ana subfolder be created in?  Are you planning to look only at ModelBuilder initially?  Personally I think you should, unless you want an ArcPy solution in which case I think you should ask for that only.

Comment: Bingo I've figured it out...